# ASP.NET MVC2 View Models Basic Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Good Morning,

I have a very simple question regarding ASP.NET MVC 2 View Models.

I have created the following view model:

```
 public class ClassifiedsListingDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int ListingID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ListedBy { get; set; }
        public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

No problems, the problems occur when trying to set the values in the controller:

```
var listing = db.Listings.Single(l => l.ListingID == id);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsListingDetailsViewModel
        {
            ListingID = listing.ListingID;


        };
```

When ever I trying and set ListingID, which is the first property of the view model it wants me to add a "," rather than a ";". Not sure how to overcome this?

Many Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with instantiating new objects. If you want to do as you say then simply write:

```
var listing = db.Listings.Single(l => l.ListingID == id);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsListingDetailsViewModel
        {
            ListingID = listing.ListingID    
        };
```

If you want to instantiate more fields then use the comma as you say:

```
        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsListingDetailsViewModel
        {
            ListingID = listing.ListingID,
            Title = "Title String"
        };
```

Comment: Oh Dear, that was a very simple question and to further this to define another property I would simply put a ",". Great, so this view models great, but it shares all but one of its properties with a database table... is there any way to get away from declaring them all over again?

Comment: You can just do as in the first example, nothing is forcing you to fill out every property